# NullPointerException when trying to read a file line by line (Java)?

Tags: java, file, path, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a file line by line, but every time I run my program I get a NullPointerException at the line `spaceIndex = line.indexOf(" ");` which obviously means that line is null. HOWEVER. I know for a fact that the file I'm using has exactly 7 lines (even if I print the value of `numLines`, I get the value 7. And yet I still get a nullpointerexception when I try to read a line into my string.

```
// File file = some File I take in after clicking a JButton

Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath(), charset)) {

    String line = "";

    int spaceIndex;
    int numLines = 0;
    while(reader.readLine()!=null) numLines++;

    for(int i = 0; i<numLines; i++) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        spaceIndex = line.indexOf(" ");
        System.out.println(spaceIndex);
}
```

PS: (I'm not actually using this code to print the index of the space, I replaced the code in my loop since there's a lot of it and it would make it longer to read)

If i'm going about reading the lines the wrong way, it would be great if someone could suggest another way, since so far every way I've tried gives me the same exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the time you start your `for` loop, the reader is already at the end of the file 
(from the `while` loop).

Therefore, `readLine()` will always return `null`.

You should get rid of the `for` loop and do all of your work in the `while` loop as you first read the file.

Comment: Oh haha, okay I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you so much.

However, I require the while loop to count the number of lines. In between the two loops I create an object based on numLines (which I left out of the code I put up), which I can't do if I put everything in one loop. Is there any way I can reset the reader to the top?

Comment: Okay I just put the reader inside the try loop and reassigned it to a `new BufferedReader(file.toPath(),charset))`, which works fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Trust: Alternatively, just make an `ArrayList<string>` to hold the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

First, you could read number of lines from a file this way:

```
LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("File1")));
lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(lnr.getLineNumber());
```

Then read the file right after:

```
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null)
{
    spaceIndex = line.indexOf(" ");
    System.out.println(spaceIndex);
}
```

This first option is an alternative (and in my my opinion, cooler) way of doing this.

Second option (and probably the more sensible) is to do it all at once in the while loop:

```
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null) 
{
    numLines++;
    spaceIndex = line.indexOf(" ");
    System.out.println(spaceIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into LineNumberReader